# Проблемы с дизайном при помощи градиента

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, градиент

Ребят, столкнулся с проблемой оформления секции `header`. Судя по всему, должны использоваться изображение и градиент, но у меня получается не то, что показано на макете.

**Прошу помочь с проблемой**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <title>Drone Zone</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>

    </header>
</body>
</html>




    body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2500px;
    background: url(images/Layer4copy.png) no-repeat center center, linear-gradient(to right, rgb(203, 0, 53), rgb(224, 105, 53));
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[image: myResult]
[image: Photoshop]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы реализовать использование и градиента, и фона одновременно для одного элемента, необходимо обратить внимание на, собственно, свойство background:

```
header {
    background: url(images/Layer4copy.png) no-repeat center center, linear-gradient(to right, rgb(203, 0, 53), rgb(224, 105, 53));  
}
```

Во-первых, когда задаётся два и более фонов, вначале указывается тот, который выводится поверх остальных, а последним, соответственно, самый нижний. В вашем случае градиент должен перекрывать изображение, то есть его необходимо указать первым.

```
header {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to right, rgb(203, 0, 53), rgb(224, 105, 53)), // градиент должен покрывать изображение, поэтому его значение задаётся первым
    url(images/Layer4copy.png) no-repeat center center; 
}
```

Во-вторых, чтобы изображение было видно под градиентом, необходимо добавить к нему непрозрачность, то есть задавать цвет необходимо с помощью rgba().

```
header {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to right, rgba(203, 0, 53, 0.5), rgba(224, 105, 53, 0.5)), // допустим, необходима 50% непрозрачность
    url(images/Layer4copy.png) no-repeat center center; 
}
```